# Static linking issue with SQLite (Mingw-w64 / gcc 4.8.1)

Tags: c++, gcc, sqlite, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile my application along with sqlite3.c but getting dozens of compile errors, all of which are sourced from sqlite3.c. If I use dynamic linking instead of static, it compiles fine.

This command fails

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp sqlite3.c -o main.exe -static -lws2_32 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

Whereas this one runs smoothly

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe -L./ -lsqlite3 -lws2_32 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

What is wrong with my command line?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
Below is the first and last error messages...There are about 4900 lines!

```
sqlite3.c:29081:37: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
     sqlite3_snprintf(nBuf-18, zBuf, "%s/"SQLITE_TEMP_FILE_PREFIX, zDir);
....
....
....
sqlite3.c:122602:20: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   db->aDb[0].zName = "main";
                    ^
sqlite3.c:122604:20: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   db->aDb[1].zName = "temp";
                    ^
sqlite3.c: In function 'int sqlite3_open16(const void*, sqlite3**)':
sqlite3.c:122746:50: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
   zFilename8 = sqlite3ValueText(pVal, SQLITE_UTF8);
                                                  ^
```

Comment: Please add the output of both the failing command and the successful command.  I have an idea what's wrong, but it would help everyone if you gave us (much) more of the picture.

Comment: Thanks @lornix ... There are more lots of errors that GCC is complaining about, I think it may be some sort of C++11 issue?

Comment: You're compiling C source as C++, don't do that. Compile the `sqlite3.c` separately with `gcc` (or `cc1`) and _then_ link them.

Comment: Thanks compiling and then linking separately worked fine.